# how to detect aura:iteration has loaded?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rerender

I need to trigger a jQuery from Rerender after my aura:iteration has completed. Based on the official document, rerender fires each time when there is a event. But the my javascript code needs to be executed once after aura:iteration has loaded. I also found that there is an attribute call "[loaded](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_iteration.htm)" in aura:iteration. But I can't find any reference on how to access aura:iteration's loaded attribute from renderer file.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have time to write a full sample, but here's some sample component markup for binding the loaded attribute to an aura:attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="items"           type="String[]" default="['one', 'two', 'three']"/>
<aura:attribute name="iterationLoaded" type="Boolean"  default="false"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item" loaded="{!v.iterationLoaded}">
    Item = {!item}<br/>
</aura:iteration><br/>

itemsLoaded = {!v.iterationLoaded}
```

When I put this on a page, the items display and the iterationLoaded attribute displays as true.

It should be possible to put a change handler on the iterationLoaded attribute so that when it changes from false to true, a controller method is called which can run any needed code.

Or, an afterRender method could check that this attribute is true before doing any further processing.

Hope this helps!